# Send special characters through AJAX ( "&lt" , "&gt" , "&amp" )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, htmlspecialchars

I send some test through jquery's ajax request.
This text contains some special characters like "&lt" , "&gt" , "&amp", which stand for <, >, and &.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "page.php",
 data: "content="+txt });
```

Unfortunately, the string is not well transmitted. Only the beginning is transmitted, and it is cut at the first special character.

For instance, if I send "blablabla&ltgrogrogro", the server only receive "blablabla"

How can I fix that?

PS: The special characters actually end with a ";", I did not put it because otherwise they are not well displayed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

& represents another variable in your data query string. So, you should send it by using a JavaScript object like so:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "page.php",
    data: {
        "content": txt
    }
});
```

Comment: That is a JavaScript object, [not a JSON object](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

Comment: It will still post your data to your page.php. So you would access it with $_POST. And thanks @Quentin.

Answer (score 2):

This is by design: If you pass a string to `data`, it will be treated as form URLencoded data (like a query string). In that format,  `&` signifies the start of a new parameter. Ampersands in data need to be URLencoded.

You would need to either URLencode your data before transmission - in PHP, the right function would be `urlencode()` - or pass an array that jQuery will encode automatically:

```
data: {"content": txt }
```

Comment: Technically, it is application/x-www-form-urlencoded data, which is the standard way to encode data in a query string, and it would be treated as a query string by JSON if a GET request was being made.

Comment: @Quentin true, seeing as the data is going to be POSTed. Thanks